# Foreach loop goes too fast

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is the loop I'm working with:

```
client.users.forEach(user => {
    if (user.presence.status == "online") {
        fnHistory.userUpdate(user.id, status, false, message);
    }
});
```

And the function inside calls this:

```
client.channels.get("495635013073895429").fetchMessage("495636761926434818").then(message => {
    message.edit(`${message.content} \n \t - ${name}`);
});
```

I'm trying to append an existing message with a new name. But after the foreach loop it only shows the last name.

This is how it goes with 2 elements in the foreach ['foo', 'bar']:

1. Before foreach: "Currently tracking:"
2. First iteration: takes"Currently tracking:" and appends it with " - foo"
3. Second iteration: takes "Currently tracking:" and appends it with " - bar". (**But it should take "Currently tracking: - foo" and then append it with " - bar"**)
4. Finishes like "Currently tracking: - bar"

I've searched a lot and already tried making every function use a promise but the foreach doesn't care about that. I also tried using a delay/timeout.
But no success...

Comment: Return the promise and use `map` not `forEach`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes I saw that solution, but that is used to track when they are all done (correct me if I'm wrong). What I want is to go to the next iteration of the foreach when one is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished in several ways. But before we get started, you need to modify your processing function to return the promise like so

```
 function () {
    return client.channels.get("495635013073895429")
  .fetchMessage("495636761926434818").then(message => {
message.edit(`${message.content} \n \t - ${name}`);
    });
}
```

Then you can serialize the processing by using `reduce` or by writing an `async` function.

**using reduce:**

```
client.users.reduce((previousIteration, user => {
  if (user.presence.status === "online") {
    return previousIteration.then(() => fnHistory.userUpdate(user.id, status, false, message));
  }
  return previousIteration;
}, Promise.resolve());
```

**using an async function:**

```
async function updateOnlineUsers() {
  for (const user of client.users) {
    if (user.presence.status === "online") {
      await fnHistory.userUpdate(user.id, status, false, message));
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried your method using the reduce, but it gives me this error `previousIteration.then is not a function`. So far I know I copied exactly what you gave me.

Comment: @SjaakvBrabant I updated it to handle empty arrays. If it still doesn't work then you are not returning the promise and more information about `fnHistory.userUpdate` is necessary